# wordpress logged-in users' total events number

Tags: ajax, wordpress, real-time

I am wondering how to show the number of real-time input users for a specific post on Wordpress website.

(For example, total signed-in users number is 10 and there are 5(A, B, C, D, E) posts on the web; among them, now 3 users are writing comments for the post B and 2 users for the post E.

The real-time output: Now commenting is progressing on post B | 3 users, post E | 2 users.)

In my naive thought, ajax will help it.

Comment: Probably the only way to do this is via the Heartbeat API, have a look [here](http://wptavern.com/pulse-an-example-wordpress-plugin-using-the-heartbeat-api) and [here](https://github.com/micc83/wp-heartbeat-notify) for more information.

Comment: thanks a lot... i'll check the api.